# Pointwise and uniform convergence of $\sum_{n = 1}^\infty\frac{e^{-n}}{n} (\ln x)^n$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I am going to completely study this series for the types of convergence I am interested in (pointwise and uniform)

$$\sum_{n = 1}^\infty\frac{e^{-n}}{n} (\ln x)^n$$

Where $x > 0$ with the intent that someone will correct me if I am wrong.

I read some post on the meta that this can be boring for answerers, so I will try to point out the passages I am more dubious about.

For point-wise convergence I use the root test and see that

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{e^{-1}}{n^{1/n}} \ln x = \frac{\ln x}{e}< 1 \iff x < e^e $$

also at $x = e^e $ the series diverges.

Now for uniform convergence I take $a < e^e$ and proceed by looking at

$$\sup_{x \in (0,a]} [ \frac{e^{-n}}{n} (\ln x)^n  ] \le \frac{e^{-n}}{n} (\ln a)^n $$

So this implies that my series converges uniformly on all intervals of the type $(0,a]$? or do I have to exclude $0$ from the bounds? is this last inequality correct?

Comment: Actually the root test yields the condition that $|\log x|<e$, not $\log x<e$, hence the interval of convergence is $[e^{-e},e^e)$, certainly not $(0,e^e)$. The rest, including domains of uniform convergence, should follow.

Comment: @Did Thanks a lot.